# Webpack dev-server with custom loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a custom webpack loader that I use with inline notation.

When I use webpack-dev-server and change some code in the loader itself, the bundle is rebuild but the changes of the loader do not apply.... I seems that it always uses a cached version of the first build for the loader...

Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: AFAIK Webpack does not watch loader/plugins files for changes. It only watches the source files. But you can add dependencies to your loader using the `addDependency(path)` function, and it will recompile when these files change.

Comment: @YoavKadosh Thank you. Tested it but as I understand it, it only watches external files that would not be under control of webpack.... dependencies to not solve the "invalidate loader on changes" issue